# Generalizing the Euclidean algorithm in several variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f, g\in k [x, y, z] $, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. If the two polynomials do not share a single zero, do there exist polynomials $m,  n\in k [x, y, z] $ such that $mf+ng=1$? I suppose I'm looking for a generalization of the Euclidean algorithm in several variables.

Comment: The answer is yes. If you have no idea, I suggest you read a bit more about ideals, Nullstellensatz etc. They will all be helpful.

Comment: @Mohan- I am aware of Nullstellensatz. Does that give an expkicit algorithm though?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the [Weak Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_Nullstellensatz).  Given a set of polynomials $S \subseteq k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, let $\mathbb{V}(S) = \{(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in k^n : f(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = 0 \text{ for all } f \in S\}$ be the simultaneous vanishing set of $S$.  The weak form of the Nullstellensatz says that for an ideal $I \trianglelefteq k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, $\mathbb{V}(I) = \varnothing$ if and only if $1 \in I$.  That is, the polynomials have no simultaneous zero if and only if the ideal they generate is the whole ring.

With regard to your question about algorithms, see the section of the linked article on the Effective Nullstellensatz.  Using [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis), one can determine if a collection of polynomials generates the whole ring.  If $\langle f_1, \ldots, f_t \rangle = \langle 1 \rangle$, [Buchberger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger's_algorithm), which is used to compute Gröbner bases, will provide you with $a_1, \ldots, a_t \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ such that $a_1 f_1 + \cdots + a_t f_t = 1$.